# Protocol from customCell to ViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I’ve a custom cell and in the custom cell I have a textField and I would like to know how can I make a protocol from the customCell class to call a function in my ViewController. I have did some code but stuck.

My issue is once I touch the textField I want to call a function from my ViewController.

```
class FirstViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, MySearchDelegate {

var search:SearchTableViewCell = SearchTableViewCell()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
    search.delegate = self

    }
}
```

My customCell class:

```
@objc protocol MySearchDelegate{
    optional func textFieldTouched()
}

class SearchTableViewCell: UITableViewCell, UITextFieldDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var searchField: UITextField!

    // this is where I declare the protocol
    var delegate:MySearchDelegate?

    func searchStart(){
        delegate?.textFieldTouched!()
    }

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        searchField.addTarget(self, action: Selector("searchStart"), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.ValueChanged)
    }

    func searchStart(){
        delegate?.textFieldTouched()
    }

    override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Altered your code to avoid strong reference cycles and conforming to your protocol:

```
    var search:SearchTableViewCell = SearchTableViewCell()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        search.delegate = self
    }

    func textFieldTouched() {
        println("voila")
    }

}

protocol MySearchDelegate: class {
    func textFieldTouched()
}

class SearchTableViewCell: UITableViewCell, UITextFieldDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var searchField: UITextField!

    // this is where I declare the protocol
    weak var delegate:MySearchDelegate?

    func searchStart(){
        delegate?.textFieldTouched()
    }

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
    }

    override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
    }

}
```

Comment: I made the change Nothing happen should I do something else?

Comment: you should connect your textfield via value changed action. then call `searchStart` from there.

Comment: I have edited my code can you please check? Is it right what I did?

Comment: you should call, somehow, to your `searchStart` function. One way to do this is by implementing the `UITextField` delegate on `SearchTableViewCell Class` and call it from there. Is similar to what @rshev said.

Comment: @Lucho I have did the UITextField delegate and I can see from the debug it is passing through `delegate?.textFieldTouched()` but nothing happen

Comment: @CAN what do you see in debug? what do you want it to do?

Comment: After it comes to delegate?.textFieldTouched() shouldn't I get "voila" text? @rshev

Comment: With your solution and by adding `cell.searchDelegate = self` from @Lucho answer. It works.

Answer (score 1):

I am not good on swift so it might be a mistake. You should assign the cell delegate when you create the cell.

```
     class FirstViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, MySearchDelegate {

         override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
                let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell

                // set the delegate here not in the viewDidLoad
        cell.searchDelegate = self

                return cell
            }

            func textFieldTouched(){
                 //do what you want here
            }
}
```